# [Moveit]Howto make two joints always have identical position

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot arm where I have two revolute joints (one driven and one forced) which will always have the same position (angle in my case) due the mechanical constrains of my robot.

What is the best way to implement a Moveit configuration for this kind of situation?

My first idea was threat both joints as normal Joints, and send fake axis information for the forced one from my Robot controller. This solution should work, but the motion planned would have to do extra calculation for this joint too.

I am unsure if the virtual joints could be used for this purpose.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259371/%5Bmoveit%5Dhowto-make-two-joints-always-have-identical-position/) by [Márton Miklós](https://answers.ros.org/users/26626/m%C3%A1rton-mikl%C3%B3s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The term you are looking for is [mimic joint](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint).
You can specify such joints in your urdf.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Márton Miklós](https://answers.ros.org/users/26626/m%C3%A1rton-mikl%C3%B3s/) on 2017-04-17**:
Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!